# Let $f=g$ on $[a,b]/E$ where $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ and continuous on $[a,b]$. Then $g\in\mathcal{R}[a,b]$ and $\displaystyle\int_a^b f=\int_a^bg$.

Tags: real-analysis

Note that if $E=\emptyset$, then we are finished. So suppose that $E=\{c\}$. Then by assumption we have that for every $\epsilon$>0 there exists a partition $$P=\{[x_{j-1},x_j]: 1\leq j\leq n\}$$ so that $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{3}.$$ There is no loss in generality to assume that $c\in [x_0,x_1]$. Define $M_j(f)=\displaystyle \max_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)$ and $m_j(f)=\displaystyle \min_{[x_{j-1},x_j]}f(x)$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ we can bound $M_1-m_1\geq- \displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{3(x_1-x_0)}$. Additionally, it should be noted that $g\in C[a,b]$ (and from this we have that $g$ attains its max and min on any subinterval of $[a,b]$). Then we also have the bound $m_1-M_1\geq \displaystyle -\frac{\epsilon}{3(x_1-x_0)}$. Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\epsilon}{3} &\geq& U(f,P)-L(f,P)\\
&=&\sum_j [M_j(f)-m_j(f)]\Delta x_j\\
&=& \sum_{j\neq 1} [M_j(g)-m_j(g)]\Delta x_j+[M_1(f)-m_1(f)](x_1-x_0)\\
&=&\sum_j[M_j(g)-m_j(g)]\Delta x_j +[M_1(f)-m_1(f)](x_1-x_0)-[M_1(g)-m_1(g)](x_1-x_0)\\
&\geq& U(g,P)-L(g,P)-\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{3}-\displaystyle\frac{\epsilon}{3}
\end{eqnarray*}
from whence it follows that $g\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$.

Additionally, if $f(a)=g(a)$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\int_a^bf(y)dy-\int_a^b g(y)dy\right|&\leq& \int_a^b |f(y)-g(y)|dy\\
&=&\int_a^b|f(y)-f(a)-g(y)+g(a)|dy\\
&\leq& \int_a^b\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}dy\\
&=&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
by continuity.

My question is if this proof looks okay. I have seen the proof before but thought of this one and wanted to see if there are any holes in it...

Edit: $E\subseteq [a,b]$ is a finite set and I should also of course have that $g$ is bounded.

Comment: What's $E$? $~~~$

Comment: Sorry about that, I have corrected the statement in my edit.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: My question would be if this proof is correct. I saw this problem in an old analysis book and so I thought I would try it out. Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Comment: Is $E$ of measure $0$?